# Is there a way to automate DELETE and INSERT in MySQL when new data is added?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm new to the whole database management game, so if I'm totally off base on this, and there's a better way to do this, please let me know.

I have an R script that I use to aggregate a bunch of weekly reports into a single table. I'm trying to set up the data storage in MySQL, but I'm not sure how to get the `INSERT` working automatically.

The output table from R is one week of data.

Right now I have two tables in MySQL, let's call them `Main`, and `NewWeek`.

`NewWeek` is where I send the output from R, and I essentially need to do:

```
/* delete any data already imported from NewWeek */
DELETE FROM Main
WHERE Main.`Date` = (SELECT max(Date) FROM NewWeek);

INSERT INTO Main Select * FROM NewWeek;
```

And I need to run that query every time I change `NewWeek` (i.e every time I run the R script), the insert may need to be ran multiple times during the week as we get more data, hence the need for the `DELETE` statement, to make sure we don't create duplicates.

I'm running MySQL via Amazon RDS, and I believe that creates some challenges for using Triggers, and so I'm not sure if that's an option.

Comment: You would run two statements, just like show here. One to delete, and one to insert. This is totally normal in a database. Alternatively you could make a trigger for your insert and do the delete there... but I think that type of code/action is better handled wherever you are doing the `INSERT` and not hidden in some trigger in the database.

Comment: Okay, so would it be a better approach to just pass the `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements via the R script?

Comment: I don't know R well enough to say, but if R can handle sending a DELETE and then an INSERT I would definitely go that route. Then all of your application logic resides in the same place. With the trigger you would have application logic (Deleting of current week records before insert) hiding in some mysterious place in the database which will baffle the ever loving snot out of the next person that has to debug this R script.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate the insight! I just tried adding those two queries to my R script and it works exactly as I want.

Answer (score 0):

When you start to shuffle around (equal) data between tables, there's most likely something wrong with your database layout.

In your case, I would recommend the following:

- Directly insert your recorded data to your MAIN-Table, without having a "week-table".
- If you need to tell these entries apart, either use a dynamic min/max date (as you do) when querying for data or if it's about data-approval, use a boolean column (approved true/false).

So, every "record" will be added with "approved=false" - and once a week, when you are happy with the data, you are just updating that column to "true".

Comment: I still think I need the `DELETE` command, because the data I'm inserting isn't just a stream of new values, it's a complete table that could have row level changes each day, and have rows added or removed. So, correct me if I'm wrong,  but I think the only way I can avoid duplicates is to first remove all the overlapping data from the earlier insert. In other words, I need to be able to insert the same table 5 times throughout the week, but the database should only ever store the most recent insert - because it overlaps with the prior insert. Any thoughts based on that info?